# Create a bar chart with bars colored according to a category and line on the same chart

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, bar-chart

I trained a model to predict a value and I want to make a bar chart that plots `target - prediction` for each sample, and then color these bars according to a category. I then want to add two horizontal lines for plus or minus sigma around the central axis, so it's clear which predictions are very far off. Imagine we know sigma == 0.3 and we have a dataframe

| error | sample_id | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| .1 | 1 | 'A' |
| .4 | 2 | 'A' |
| .1 | 3 | 'B' |
| -.2 | 4 | 'B' |
| -.1 | 5 | 'C' |

How could I do this? I've managed to do just the errors and the plus or minus sigma lines just using matplotlib, here it is to communicate what I mean.

[image: none]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually very easy, I just didn't understand the 'color' option of plt.bar. If it is a list of length equal to the number of bars, then it will color each bar with the corresponding color. It's as simple as

```
plt.(x,y,color = z)
#len(x) = len(y) = len(z), and z is an array of colors
```

As krukah mentions, you just need to translate categories to colors. I picked a color map, made a dictionary that picked a color for each unique category, and then turned the cats array (a 2d np array, each row encodes a category) into an array of colors.

```
unique_cats = np.unique(cats, axis=0)
n_unique = unique_cats.shape[0]
for_picking = np.arange(0,1,1/n_unique)

cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('plasma')
color_dict = {}

#this for loop fills in the dictionary by picking colors from the cmap
for i in range(n_unique):
    color_dict[str(unique_cats[i])] =cmap(for_picking[i])

color_cats = [color_dict[str(cat)] for cat in cats]
```

Hopefully that helps someone some day.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find the `pd.Series.transform()` and/or `pd.DataFrame.apply()` methods quite useful. Essentially, you can map each value of your input columns (in this case `errors`) into some valid color value, returning a `pd.Series` of colors that's the same shape as errors.

The phrasing of the question is unclear, but it sounds like you want a single pair of lines for each category? In which case, you will first need to do a `pd.Series.groupby()` operation to get the shape that you want *before* the transform opeartion. Probably just a series of length 3, for your A B C categories.

Then, this `Series` (whether it is of length `len(df)` or `df.category.nunique()`) can be passed into your `plt.bar` method as the `color` argument.

Comment: I edited my question to clarify what I mean. I intend for each vertical bar to be a different color, depending on the category column -- not the error value. For example all bars with category 'A' would be red, so on.

Comment: In that case, the data you're passing into `plt.bar` has length 3. The color of category `X` should be a function of all rows with category `X`. Probably would be something like:
`def rows_to_color(ser: pd.Series): (something mapping ser to color)` Then at this point you can do something like `bar_colors = df.groupby("category").apply(rows_to_color)`